# How to enable GZIP compression for SOAP responses?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I created a simple soap webservice using `Spring` and `CXF`. I'm now trying to enable GZIP compression for the xml requests.
The following will accept compressed requests, but will response uncompressed. Why?

```
@Component
@WebService
public class SoapService {

}

@Autowired
private SpringBus bus;


EndpointImpl end = new EndpointImpl(bus, new SoapService());
end.getFeatures().add(config.gzipFeature());
ep.publish("/SoapService");
```

Request to this SoapService:

```
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate], content-encoding=[gzip], connection=[Keep-Alive], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], ...}
```

Response (empty headers!!):

```
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers:
Payload: ...
```

Why is the response not compressed with gzip?

Comment: I will suggest to send xml message in soap body as base64 encoded string of compressed binary data and client client will decompress this encoded string.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `@GZIP` annotation to your interface.  [Here's the documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/annotations.html).  If I remember correctly you need to have `GZIPOutInterceptor` declared in your spring config.

Alternatively, you could add the [GZIPOutInterceptor](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/common/gzip/GZIPOutInterceptor.html) to your endpoint manually.

Comment: to quote myself: `end.getFeatures().add(config.gzipFeature());` this adds the GZIPOutInterceptor to the endpoint manually, already.

Comment: I would recommend dropping a break point inside GZIPOutInterceptor  to see if it's called? Maybe it's not hitting the threshold size to activate it.